# Using a Linux-powered computer without a videocard

Tags: linux

So I need a "server" for my home and work needs. This is a simple computer with an SSD, a good CPU, motherboard and some RAM. The only problem is there will be no videocard (no need in it). I know that some motherboards can run without it but how do I get to console of a Linux-powered server without a videocard?

Comment: Use the network, or a serial interface. You may need to configure the kernel.

Comment: @dirkt What about using SSH? This looks simpler to me, but it needs to be set up first. Is there a way to install a distrib with SSH ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Been there, done that...
It is most certainly possible, but can take a lot of work to get to work.

In general: If your are being paid for setting this up: Any dirt-cheap video-card will be cheaper than your billing for the time spent on it.  So rethink whether you are really want to go this route first.
(And many Intel CPU's come with an embedded GPU anyway these days. No need for this on one of those anyway.)

First you will need to find a motherboard that supports running without any video-card at all. These are very hard to find and usually expensive.
Even if you can find one chances are, you still need to temporarily install a real video-card in it, in order to get it to boot into Bios so you can re-configure it to run without a video-card (I have never seen one that has that featured enabled by default).

When you have reached that point you will have to setup a Linux install-medium (USB is easiest) that has additional boot-parameters given to the kernel that tell it to use a serial console for it's console.
You can then hook up a serial terminal (or another computer running a serial terminal application) to the serial port of the motherboard (*I hope you bought a motherboard with a real serial port that works out of the box with Linux...*) and control the setup process from there.
Getting serial console to work is finicky and usually takes a lot of trail an error to get it right. (Getting the right device-name for the serial port, baud-rate, stop-bits, etc. Some motherboards are picky about the settings and the serial console settings in Bios must match those in Linux. Often this is totally undocumented.)

When you have networking up and running you can obviously switch over to SSH for remote management.

So: It can be done, but unless you have a VERY good specific reason to attempt this, it usually isn't worth the effort.

Comment: I am not being paid for this :D I just thought that a server without video would be cheaper...

Comment: Given that a basic video-card will cost about 15-20$, which is probably less than the premium extra price for a specialist motherboard... The cost aspect is the least of you worries I think.

Comment: And integrated Intel graphics, which are already part of the Southbridge if you need a "good CPU", cost next to nothing in this setup. No need for an extra video card.

Comment: I will have a much harder time finding a motherboard that supports no video booting than one with integrated video...